# net/http : is it possible to have http.HandleFunc custom params?

Tags: go

I'm trying to find a way to create special routes to that would allow post request to work with a params ( /url/:param ).

I've tried something like this :

`http.HandleFunc("/myroute/:myparam",myfunction)`

And i was hopping to be able to get the params as of the http-request in side "myfunction" with `req.Form` but it keeps on failing on me and i get 404'ed.

I recognize it is something strange to ask as i could pass my params in the body of the function, but for ease of use/display i've been asked to be able to pregenerate a list of static "routes" on some preset so that it can be distributed as different urls + optional params instead of one url for everybody + params..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible with the default `Mux`, but you can use alternative routers like [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter), [Gorilla Mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) or [chi](https://github.com/pressly/chi).

Here is an example of `httprouter` usage:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
)

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s!\n", ps.ByName("name"))
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/hello/:name", Hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

Comment: would that work with ` router.POST("/hello/:name", Hello)` ? If i'm looking for raw speed which of the router you've listed would you recommend?

Comment: @Cam.phiefr it would. httrouter is one of the most efficient routers, you can find benchmarks at https://github.com/julienschmidt/go-http-routing-benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a handle function on `/` and then have custom parsing of the path, like splitting on `/` character.

`http.HandleFunc("/", dispatcher)`

In this way, your handler will accept everything and you can route the requests manually to the respective function. For example, PUT calls would expect some parameter after the resource (`/orders/2`)

`logs.Info("The URL that you are calling is: " + req.URL.Path)`

Output: `The URL that you are calling is: /orders/2`

You can also do:
`http.HandleFunc("/orders/", dispatcher)`
to narrow down the scope of your handler. In this way, you can leave the validation of the resource portion of the path to Go http package.